# What do you call pseudo-values in a Dropdown List (for example)

Tags: terminology

This is a simple terminology question.   If you have a dropdown list (as an example) with user-defined values, what do you call values such as "All", "None" that you might also have in the list?

For example, I might have a list of names as follows:

- (All)
- Bill
- Bob
- Susie

What term is used to refer to the "(All)" value?   I've been using the term "pseudo-value" but I pretty much just made that up.

Also, just for clarification, I'm not referring to a term that would be presented in the UI (necessarily); just a term for design discussions.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Any particular theme to the contents of the list? Is the list made up of names or something?

Comment: Could be names.   An example might be a search dialog where you can search by various attributes -- e.g. a person's name; a country; a preferred currency.   You might want to search for, say, all people in a given country or that use a given currency.   Alternatively, you might want to search for a person but you don't know the specific country so you might say "I want to find Bill in any country" (as opposed to Bill in Canada).

Comment: I think the term pseudo-value is pretty cool actually.

Comment: Could this include values like "Changed since last visit", "Popular", and other short-cut methods to selecting a group of values?

Answer (score 3):

It will most likely depend on the actual content of the list. But some *generic* suggestions:

- "catch-all" values
- "default" values
- "no-selection-made" values

Personally, I like your use of 'psuedo-value'. So, if your audience is understanding it I would carry on using it!

Comment: Thanks Chris.  "Default" would definitely not work in this case because it might not be.  For example, the default search for country might be "United States" but a user could change that to search all countries.

Comment: Completely agree Bill. I think it's likely going to depend on each specific implementation, but in all cases I can think of your "psuedo-value" name works for me. I'll be interested to see if someone comes up with a better (or even 'correct' / 'standard') term.

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo-values is fine.  *Descriptive* values or *value descriptions* is an alternative, because they don't represent a value but describe values or the absence of values.